# SOLR: How to sort by price when price not added properly?

Tags: solr

In Solr, Price values are like below

```
"Price":"0.07 AUD"
"Price":"10.00"
"Price":"AUD"
```

So while sorting, I want to ignore `"Price":"AUD"`

That's what I tried: but it doesn't work.

> Create New Field

```
<field name="CustomPrice" type="PriceFieldType" indexed="true"/>
```

> Copy Price field to CustomPrice

```
  <copyField source="Price" dest="CustomPrice"/>
```

> Create new Custom Field Type **PriceFieldType**

```
<fieldType name="PriceFieldType" class="solr.TextField">
     <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(AUD?):?\s(\[0-9-\]+)" />
     </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Take referance from here:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer

> Also Tried

```
<fieldType name="PriceFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9.])" replacement=""
             replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9.])" replacement=""
             replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Comment: if AUD is common term...remove it from indexing or store is as different field in solr and store the numeric values against the price field....

Comment: or check if you can use the Alphanumeric field type for your field

Comment: ok.. I'm trying "solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" to do this.. 
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer

Answer (score 1):

Solution could be to modify or manipulate the original field into one or more new fields. Each of the field containing alternatively the alphabetic and numeric part.

I mean separate the numeric part to one field like `fieldNumeric` and alphabet part to another field like `fieldAlpha`.

In this way you can sort the output passing the list of fields, in the order you need, to the standard sort query clause. For example:

```
sort= fieldNumeric asc, fieldAlpha asc
```

But its not mandatory to split value. You can keep one field with original value and have another field with numeric value. You can achieve the numberic value extraction by filtering the data.

I created the below field type

```
<fieldType name="text_replace" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9.]+" replacement="" replace="all"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
     </field>
```

Here is my analysis page looks like :

[image: Solr Analysis Page]

Here is the query Page :

[image: Solr Query Page]

Here is the query page with sorting on price.

[image: Solr Query Page with Sorting]

Comment: How to separate the fields? numeric and text? I need only numeric field

Comment: I tried this with new custom field but not working  === <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(AUD?):?\s(\[0-9-\]+)" />

Comment: try with <fieldType name="PriceFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> 
<analyzer> <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^0-9.]+"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: still saving same string in new field ==  "Price":"129.95 AUD",
        "CustomPrice":"129.95 AUD",

Comment: try by adding replacement="" replace="all" to pattern filter....restart solr or reload core and check on analyse page

Comment: So Abhijit, Is it not possible to remove "AUD" from the field completely and save it into another field? I want to sort by price on that field.

Comment: you still can sort on that field....the value shown is the original value....the value that is indexed is without "AUD" and its the same can used for searching and sorting

Comment: Ok.. but in some records, the price value is only "AUD" (no numbers available), in that case what should I do? can I replace blank value with 0 (zero)?

Comment: Actually I want to remove AUD word completely from the copied field.

Comment: For that you need to do pre processing of the data and then pass it solr...Pre processing can be done by writing java code and then build the solr document and then index it on solr

Comment: This link can give you some thoughts on ...https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.html

Comment: @PrashantPatil:I would suggest to raise a separate question for separating the data...the current question was about sorting the data by removing the text field...which can be achieved now..