# SOLR: how to copy data to another field with filtered values?

Tags: solr

I have `Price` field in solr with below types of values.

```
"Price":"0.07 AUD"
"Price":"10.00"
"Price":"AUD"
```

So, I need another custom field `CustomPrice`

To create this I used copy field to copy data from `Price` to `CustomPrice`

But, I need only number values into `CustomPrice` like below

```
"CustomPrice":"0.07"
"CustomPrice":"10.00"
"CustomPrice":"0"
```

Also need `CustomPrice` field type as `pfloat` so we can sort the field by number.

I tried `CopyField`, `PatternTokenizerFactory`, `PatternReplaceFilterFactory` to do this.

My old question reference : [SOLR: How to sort by price when price not added properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337224/solr-how-to-sort-by-price-when-price-not-added-properly)

So, How can I create a new float field in which I can copy only the numerical values from Price field?

> Below is the error when I set new field type as float

```
"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=12958142955618] Error adding field 'Price'='129.95 AUD' msg=For input string: \"129.95 AUD\"",
    "code":400}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the help of `Update Request Processors`. Every update request received by `Solr` is run through a chain of plugins known as `Update Request Processors`.

This can be useful, for example, to add a field to the document being indexed; to change the value of a particular field; or to drop an update if the incoming document doesn’t fulfill certain criteria.

You can add a processor in order to achieve the same.

The processor is :

```
<processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
            <str name="fieldName">price</str>
            <str name="pattern">[^0-9.]+</str>
            <str name="replacement"></str>
            <bool name="literalReplacement">true</bool>
       </processor>
```

The processor can be added to the `updateRequestProcessorChain` as below

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
   <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">price</str>
        <str name="pattern">[^0-9.]+</str>
        <str name="replacement"></str>
        <bool name="literalReplacement">true</bool>
   </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>

  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Add this entry to you managed schema file.

```
<field name="copyFloatPrice" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
<copyField source="price" dest="copyFloatPrice"/>
```

When I query the solr I get the below data. I could achieve the sorting on the `copyFloatPrice`.

[image: SOlr Query Page]

---

Here is the changes done.

The change in the `solrConfig.xml`.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
   <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
        <str name="source">price</str>
        <str name="dest">copyFloatPrice</str> 
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">copyFloatPrice</str>
        <str name="pattern">[^0-9.]+</str>
        <str name="replacement"></str>
        <bool name="literalReplacement">true</bool>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">copyFloatPrice</str>
        <str name="pattern">^$</str>
        <str name="replacement">0</str>
        <bool name="literalReplacement">true</bool>
   </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

The changes made in the `managed-schema` file are :

```
<field name="price" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="copyFloatPrice" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
```

The solr query response which shows the data indexed for `price`, `copyFloatPrice` and sorting achieved.

[image: Solr Response final]

Comment: Updated the answer...are you using managed schema...? check the field name for price field

Comment: Is this removes 'AUD' from Price field as well?

Comment: I need Original text in Price field with 'AUD'

Comment: that could be achieved with earlier solution....keep the original field as price...copy the data for copyField called as copyPrice....apply the regex to it..the field named copyPrice will have the only number and original price will be as it is...

Comment: Another way can be add the cloneFieldProcessor as below <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
       <str name="source">price</str>
       <str name="dest">copyFloatPrice</str>
     </processor>...

Comment: can you please give me an example of this? I added this clonefieldupdateProcessorFactory in solrconfig.xml but got an error. ==  "msg":"ERROR: [doc=12958142955618] Error adding field 'Price'='129.95 AUD' msg=For input string: \"129.95 AUD\"",

Comment: Also Can we set CustomPrice=0 if Price is null after removing AUD

Comment: Thanks Abhijit.. it works perfects.. I have another question on this.. please check once if you can help on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387808/solr-copy-record-from-second-field-if-1st-field-is-null-or-not-available

Comment: it worked.. I did the same using solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory But I'm afraid that the new field content is not used for searching. I am not getting results from those. Do you have any idea.? @abhijit-bashetti

Comment: @NeenuChandran, sorry did not get the question.

Comment: For me, text search works well.. Now my requirement is to index images from those urls and should be capable of give img urls when searching with image name... so what I did was, in solrconfig.xml file,  I added an updateRequestProcessorChain. where id(which is the url of the page/image) will be copied to a feild name imageName and using regex filter, I will extract image name from the url( As you sugggested and using ur example). I can see a field imgName in everyresult set while searching for another keyword, but searching with img names gives no results.This is my issue.. @abhijit-bashetti

Comment: is your field defined in schema file? does it have the value indexed=true?

Comment: Yes.. ``<field name="imgName" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>``

Comment: Also, I added this even if Im not sure whether this is required or not . ``<copyField source="url" dest="imgName"/>``

Comment: Remove the later...I dont think its require...we dont want to copy the url to imgName...requestPreocessor will take care of it...As you have added copyField its overridding the imageName

Comment: Oh.. but I'm getting extracted content as the image name.. I will try by removing it and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234077/discussion-between-neenuchandran-and-abhijit-bashetti).