# SOLR: Copy record from second field if 1st field is null or not available

Tags: solr

> Followed by this question: 
>   [SOLR: how to copy data to another field with filtered values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375355/solr-how-to-copy-data-to-another-field-with-filtered-values)

I have these types of values in solr

```
"Price":"0.07 AUD"
"Price":"10.00"
"Price":"AUD"
```

So, I copied the above records into another field as below

```
"CustomPrice":0.07
"CustomPrice":10.00
"CustomPrice": 0.0
```

Now I have another field `PriceSale`, So If the `Price is NULL` I want to copy `PriceSale` into `CustomPrice`

```
"PriceSale":"45.43 AUD",
"PriceSale":"5.40 AUD",
"PriceSale":"40.30 AUD",
```

so if the `"CustomPrice": 0.0` then `PriceSale` price should copy into `CustomPrice` as below

```
"CustomPrice":0.07
 "CustomPrice":10.00
 "CustomPrice": 40.30
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What the point in storing value in CustomPrice when Price is NULL? and what value to store in CustomPrice in that case?

Comment: actually, when Price is null at that time there is value in SalePrice column

Comment: Thats why when Price is null then I want store SalePrice value into CustomPrice field

Comment: Please provide the appropriate data and the condition clearly...mention which all fields are the part of solr document...and how exactly is the document structure

Comment: Ok.. Editing the question with more details

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way you can try and get the things working for you.
Implementing a conditional copyField implemenation as below.

```
package mysolr;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest;
import org.apache.solr.response.SolrQueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand;
import org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor;
import org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorFactory;

public class ConditionalCopyProcessorFactory extends UpdateRequestProcessorFactory
{
  @Override
  public UpdateRequestProcessor getInstance(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp, UpdateRequestProcessor next)
  {
    return new ConditionalCopyProcessor(next);
  }
}

class ConditionalCopyProcessor extends UpdateRequestProcessor
{
  public ConditionalCopyProcessor( UpdateRequestProcessor next) {
    super( next );
  }

  @Override
  public void processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    SolrInputDocument doc = cmd.getSolrInputDocument();

    Object v = doc.getFieldValue( "Price" );
    if( v == "AUD" ) {
      Object priceSaleObject = doc.getFieldValue( "PriceSale" );
      float priceSale = Float.parseFloat( priceSaleObject.toString() );
      doc.addField("CustomPrice", priceSale);
      //addField(String name,Object value)
    }

    // pass it up the chain
    super.processAdd(cmd);
  }
}
```

With this code you need to create a jar named `"ConditionalCopyProcessorFactory.jar"`.

In the `solrConfig.xml`, please add the following changes.

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/plugins/" regex="ConditionalCopyProcessorFactory.jar" />

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="mysolr.ConditionalCopyProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```